# Why is there a 3 hour minimum delay in email notification?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, email

Why is there a minimum 3 hour delay in receiving notifications via email.

I like to receive the notification by email more frequently, especially when I'm away from the site and not looking at the top bar. As long as it doesn't send out emails when you're on the site and you've checked the notifications from the to bar, spamming the inbox shouldn't be a concern.

Limit should be (allowed to be) lowered further down, all the way down to instant email notification.

Comment: What would you do with those emails, if you're not near a device capable of showing you the Stack Overflow question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean I'm away from the SO site, tabbed away on some other site, or just not using the browser and doing other things on the device capable of displaying SO.

Comment: There's a whole lot of apps out there that can notify you way more efficiently than email.

Comment: @roippi I haven't found that there are very many good ones. SEI could probably provide a better official option.

Comment: @JeremyBanks, did you look [here](http://stackapps.com/)?

Comment: [There are currently no apps that work on Windows](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/windows)

Comment: Let's face it, it sucks that the minimum delay for receiving notifications is 3 hours. One should at least have the possibility to set it to 5 minutes or instantaneous if you like. How about if we stop arguing for a moment and change the code quickly.